# Passing object reference of different classes through Object class

Tags: java

I have a utility class `A` which contains `operation()` method . There are two other classes `B` and `C`. `B` and `C` contains a method `add()`. I want to call `add()` method of class `B` or `C` from class `A` `operation()` method.

Depending upon the reference passed of a class for ex : `B` or `C` I would like the compiler to decide which class of `add()` method to call.

So, for this, I tried like this, by passing reference of class `B` I want to call `add()` method of `B`

```
new A().operation( new B())
```

Now in A class, I am receiving the reference in `Object` class as it should be able to hold the reference of both `B` and `C` class

so, the code is

```
class A{
public void operation(Object obj){
obj.add();
}   
}
```

I am getting compilation error that it couldn't add() method in `Object` class, My question is why is it finding the method in Object class, It holds the object reference of class `B`. Am i doing it correctly or is there a better approach in this scenario?

Comment: The usual approach would be to define a common Interface that B and C implement with the add method, than have your class A accept any object of said interface.

Comment: Yeah, that make sense. thank you.

Comment: Your object is being upcast to type Object that doesn't posses the method add() if you want this behaviour you will need to implement a common interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public interface CommonInterface{
     public void add();
} 

public class B implements CommonInterface{
  public void add(){
      .......
   }
}
public class C implements CommonInterface{
   public void add(){
      .......
 }
}
public class A{
   public void operation(CommonInterface obj){
     obj.add();
   }
 }
```

Now you can call new A().operation( new B());
new A().operation( new C())